# Robospice - Upload InputStreamResource

Tags: java, android, spring

I have some difficulty (I just spent an afternoon above) to upload an image with a `InputStreamResource`, here is my current code :

```
    MultiValueMap<String, Object> parts = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>();

    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); 
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.PNG, 0, bos); 
    bos.toByteArray();

    ByteArrayInputStream bs = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());      
    parts.add("photo", new InputStreamResource(bs));


    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
    HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> request = new HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>>(parts, headers);


    RestTemplate template = getRestTemplate();
    template.setErrorHandler(new MyDefaultReponseErrorHandler());
    template.getMessageConverters().add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());

    return template.postForObject("http://bottlapp.cleverapps.io/api/pic", request, Result.class);
```

and traces generated :

> 03-29 19:00:45.438: E//RequestRunner.java:134(18769): 19:00:45.454 Thread-28593 An exception occurred during request network execution :org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource cannot be cast to java.lang.String
>   03-29 19:00:45.438: E//RequestRunner.java:134(18769): java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.core.io.InputStreamResource cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Someone could help me ?

Thanks you.